# Node.js: Installation of modules hangs forever on "addRemoteTarBall"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I tried getting several modules but every time installation hangs forever. I tried with `--verbose` flag and I received this message on picture. I can't figure out where is problem.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Vlado, what npm module were you trying to install?

Comment: Bower, but some is happening whatever module I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Just give it some time. These can be quite slow.

Comment: From the morning. Is that enough?

Comment: @Vlado ok, that's a bit too long. Does this happen for all modules? Make sure Node is set up correctly. Restart the cmd and/or the computer.

Comment: I restarted everything several times and reinstalled node. It is happening with all modules.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? @Vlado

Comment: And running ``npm install -g bower`` also results in this infinite "installation"? Also, do you have Git installed?

Comment: Yes. I put git in console. I didn't get error, so git is installed.

Comment: And Python as well? @Vlado

Comment: Also, it looks like your NPM install is outdated. The latest version should be 2.7.4 while you have 2.5.1.

Comment: @Vlado did you ever get this resolved? I am unable to think of a fix, sorry.

Comment: I reinstalled git also but I still get some errors. I don't know which other dependencies npm have. I reinstalled node and git but situation i completely the same.